# Mosfet driver(Pin configuration)

Tags: mosfet, gate-driving

I would like to know what Vcc(supply voltage) and Vin(input voltage) do on Gate driver.

Here is the datasheet.

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2813.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Clarification from comments: Vcc is the supply voltage *and* reference for the input circuits, and as a result sets your input thresholds.  According to the datasheet, it is happy receiving between 4 and 14 V, and this will power the gate driver.  Vcc should not exceed 15 V.

There is a separate regulator, and probably the best way to describe it is this sentence from datasheet pg 14: "The regulator can be used to limit V
CC to between 10 V and 13 V for a range of input voltages from 14 V to 40 V, while providing up to 20 mA of dc drive."

Vin isn't mentioned but I'm assuming you are referring to 1IN and 2IN.  These are the command signals to turn the MOSFET on and off.  The table on datasheet pg 5 will give you the voltage ranges that it will operate at.

The narrative on datasheet pg 14 is a good place to start too.

Kudos to the OP for finding one of the funkier gate drivers I've seen.

Comment: Actually, VCC is not the supply voltage on the TPS2813 - easy mistake to make because the data sheet has a number of different configurations.

Comment: Correction - Vcc is the supply voltage for the MosFET drivers and the internal logic. REG_IN in only the input to a regulator whose output is REG_OUT. Some versions of the chip do not include the regulator. Vcc is also the reference for the logic inputs, which is one reason this chip is so lame.

Comment: I might not use the regulator input. Functional block diagram on pg 2 indicate that output1 is dependent on input 1 and Vcc. But, I do not understand how this works.

Comment: You are correct - my apologies

Answer (score 0):

The TPS 2813 has a regulator that allows for up to 40 volts for power to the driver chip.  Most FETs won't like 40 volts on the gate, so it is regulated down to drive the gate between 10 and 13 volts.

VCC is a reference for the digital inputs.  If you are using 5 volt logic, put 5 volts here.  Same for 10 volt logic.  There is hysteresis on the input, and the thresholds go up and down with VCC.

Comment: Before the gate driver, I send pulse signal on gate and DC signal on drain. Then, Which pin of gate driver should I use for pulse signal? Output1 would connect to the gate of MOSFET.